# LINQ saying invalid arguments for insertonsubmit

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql, invalid-argument, insertonsubmit

I seem to be running into this issue with inserting data into a table in a SQL Server 08R2 using LINQ in C#. No matter what I've tried I keep getting an error with `INSERTONSUBMIT()`.
Here is the code...

```
private void testUpdateUNITBC()
{
      using (unitDataContext unit = new unitDataContext())
      {
            unitnotest unitbc = new unitnotest();
                 unit.FBARCO = "1234";
                 unit.FUNITNO = "1234";
                 unit.FJOBNO = "I9999-0000";
                 unit.FBOXNO = "999";
                 unit.FOPNO = "999";

             unit.UNITBCs.InsertOnSubmit(unitbc); <--this is where I get the error
       };
```

The error reads

> void Table.InsertOnSubmit(UNITBC entity)
>   Adds an entity in a pending insert state to this System.Data.Linq.Table.
>   Error:
>        The best overloaded method match for 'System.Data.Linq.Table.InsertOnSubmit(AS5553.UNITBC)' has some invalid arguments

The container I used to hold the variables matches the table datatypes. (`string` to `varchar(64)`)
I know I need the `unit.SubmitChanges();` next but it doesn't matter as I can't get passed the `INSERTONSUBMIT()` point. Any help would be great as I've tried several things and spent the entire day working on this with research.

**Update**

Here is the unitnotest class as requested...

```
    public class unitnotest 
{ 
     public string FBARCO {get;set;}
     public string FUNITNO {get;set;}
     public string FJOBNO {get;set;}
     public string FBOXNO {get;set;}
     public string FOPNO {get;set;}
}
```

Comment: can you post the construct of unitnotest?

Comment: The error says `InsertOnSubmit(UNITBC entity)` is expecting UNITBC type and you are passing `unitnotest`

Answer (score 2):

It seems that the `EntityObject` of type `unitnotest` is different from the `EntityObject` of the `ObjectSet` of type `UNITBCs`.

Means you are trying to insert the wrong object.

Comment: ok, that's what I thought; however, every example in the world shows inserting the container with the information as InsertOnSubmit(unitbc)... http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386941.aspx per microsoft. Can you or anyone clarify on this for me?

Comment: @saturnnine  the link you post: notice db.Orders / new order() versus in your case db.UNITBCs / new unitnotest() ; there is your difference